# Check if process is running Mac OS X then execute code

Tags: shell-script, osx, macintosh

I am creating a script which clears the cache for Google Chrome. However, I would like to check if Chrome is open and if so not run the code but if it isn't then it will execute the code. I can see that the Process Name is Google Chrome but the code doesn't work.

This is what I have done so far. What am I doing wrong?

```
SERVICE='Google Chrome'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE
then
    RUNS THE CODE
else
    echo "PLEASE CLOSE GOOGLE CHROME"
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @StéphaneChazelas mentions, you can use `pgrep` - from the man page:

> The pgrep command searches the process table on the running system and prints the process IDs of all processes that match the criteria given on the command line.

```
SERVICE='Google Chrome'

if pgrep -xq -- "${SERVICE}"; then
    echo running
else
    echo not running
fi
```

Comment: Or `pgrep -xq -- "$SERVICE"`. Note that not all `pgrep` implementations support `-q`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, `-x` is nicer.  I'm assuming the OSX `pgrep`, since that is how the question was tagged.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote "$SERVICE":

```
SERVICE='Google Chrome'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "${SERVICE}" &> /dev/null; then
    echo running
else
    echo not running
fi
```

Comment: Or just `pgrep -f "$SERVICE"`. Note that it would return true as long as there's a process that has `Google Chrome` in its argument list, so is not fool-proof and generally not the right way to check that a service is running.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas why specify the `-f` at all? *-f          Match against full argument lists.  The default is to match against process names.*  Without the `-f` I think we just match against process name which is what is needed here, right?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, `ps ax` prints the argument list, not the process name. Without knowing what `ps ax` prints for that particular process, I just gave the `pgrep` equivalent of what was being proposed.